# Use "them" or "it", when refering to the abstract concept, fears

Tags: grammar, word-usage, abstract-nouns

Use "them" or "it", when refering to the abstract concept, fears.

"Let’s put our fears in a little bottle and use it as a 
garnish for meals, or sprinkle some on popcorn for scary movies."

OR

"Let’s put our fears in a little bottle and use them as a garnish for meals, or sprinkle some on popcorn for scary movies."

"Fears" is plural, so should i use them? The sentence is poetic, so i am not sure. What sounds better?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you have to use the plural pronoun to refer back to the plural noun *fears*.

Answer (score 2):

Using 'them' makes 'fears' the garnish for meals.  Presumably the intended meaning.

Using 'it' makes the bottle itself the garnish (surely not).  It also contadicts the clearly uncountable popcorn ('some').

Comment: brief, clear, and correct.